# Spring Boot How to Convert the return Date to String

Tags: java

No converter found for return value of type: class java.time.LocalDateTime

```
 @RequestMapping("/hello2")
    @ResponseBody
    public LocalDateTime handleRequest2(@RequestParam @DateTimeFormat(iso = DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE_TIME)LocalDateTime dateTime) throws Exception {

        return dateTime;
    }
```

(well ,i konw can write the return type as String) ,i guess spring framework have an util whic can convert an object to string , i just want to know how can i do ,to make the datetime convert string json.

Comment: you need `jackson-databind` dependency

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the below dependency to your `pom.xml` :

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
    <version>2.10.0.pr3</version>
</dependency>
```

It would give you options to achieve what you want!

Comment: but why, can you give me some hint,i want to know the reason

Comment: Please refer to : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57454213/why-do-we-need-jackson-databind for details.